# Why does Kubuntu no longer prompt for a reboot after a kernel upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, kubuntu, kde

I run Kubuntu (currently 21.04 Hirsute, getting ready to dist-upgrade to 21.10 Impish) and check for updates daily. I do it from Konsole:

sudo apt update

sudo apt full-upgrade

For as long as I can remember, whenever there was a new kernel, a little reboot icon would appear in the system tray. When clicked, it would ask for confirmation and then reboot.
For a while now, this has no longer been the case. Does this mean:

(a) I no longer need to reboot for a new kernel, or

(b) There are cases where it's ok to continue running the old kernel, and KDE doesn't want to nag me, or

(c) I broke something?

Comment: I am using Kubuntu 20.04 and use a script to update. I do get a pop-up and typically reboot immediately anyway. There is a notification icon in lower right. I had several other notices in it, but after looking, it disappeared. Did you turn notifications off?

Comment: Thanks, oldfred, I didn't know I could do that. In System Settings I see there are lots of options regarding notifications, but all the right boxes seem to be checked by default, including "Required reboots". Perhaps kernel updates that don't include security patches don't require a reboot? Even so, it's been a very long time since I've seen that icon.